# Can I add <area> to the onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to add a <area to a onmouseover event. I'm wondering that's possible or not? I know the <area should under <map but how can I achieve a similar effect for the onmouseover.[image]

Lets say my mouse is current over beverages, and how can I make box "Pack25" clickable.
My code is here:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body> 
    <h1>Product Catagories</h1>
    <img id="basic" src="graph/All.jpg"></img>
   <table border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td id="frozen_food" ><img src="graph/frozenoff.jpg"></img></td>
            <td id="fresh_food" > <img src="graph/freshoff.jpg"></img></td>
            <td id="beverages"><img src="graph/beveoff.jpg"></img></td>
            <td id="home_health"><img src="graph/homeoff.jpg"></img></td>
            <td id="pet_food"><img src="graph/petoff.jpg"></img></td>
        </tr>
        
    </table>
    <img id="detail" src=""></img>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function showpic(td){
            var shopping_item = td.getAttribute("id");
            var detail = document.getElementById("detail");
            if (shopping_item == "frozen_food"){
                detail.src="graph/Frozen_detail.jpg"
            }
            else if (shopping_item == "fresh_food"){
                detail.src ="graph/fresh_detail.jpg"
            }else if(shopping_item == "beverages"){
                detail.src = "graph/beve_detail.jpg"
            }else if(shopping_item == "home_health"){
                detail.src ="graph/home_detail.jpg"
            }else if(shopping_item == "pet_food"){
                detail.src = "graph/pet_detail.jpg"
            }
        }
        var frozen_food = document.getElementById("frozen_food");
        frozen_food.onmouseover = function(){
            showpic(frozen_food);
        }
        var fresh_food = document.getElementById("fresh_food");
        fresh_food.onmouseover = function(){
            showpic(fresh_food);
        }
        var beverages = document.getElementById("beverages");
        beverages.onmouseover = function(){
            showpic(beverages);
        }
        var home_health = document.getElementById("home_health");
        home_health.onmouseover = function(){
            showpic(home_health);
        }
        var pet_food = document.getElementById("pet_food");
        pet_food.onmouseover = function(){
            showpic(pet_food);
        }
    </script>  
</body>
```

Any hints will be appreciate~Thank you.